# Convert String-Column containing Epoch Timestamps to Date-Column when scheme is unknown

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have several tables the Dataflow reads from JSON-Files. Some of the String-Columns therein are actually Epoch Timestamps, but, since there quite a few tables and I don't want to make one dataflow per table, I can't manually tell the Source what column-type it's supposed to use.

I've tried using a DerivedColumn-Modifier, but there you have to filter which columns to modify before looking at the content of the column.
Setting a default format for Time in the Source failed as well, though admittedly setting it the Time to 'mmmmmmmmmmmmm' was a bit of a longshot.
Now it seems like I'm stuck between the unpalatable options of hardcoding the exact name of every column that's supposed to be a Date/Time into the DerivedColumn and maybe adapting the target Database to try and convert that in a later step.
I'd very much like to avoid either scenario.
Is there way to achieve this that I forgot or, more likely, just didn't know about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by taking a step back and first querying the the DB, into which the JSON-data was supposed to go, to see which columns had time-based datatypes, converting the return into an String-Array variable and passing the thing to the dataflow as a parameter. With that Array, the DerivedColumn could just match the column-names it was supposed to convert.

The only minor hiccup was, when one column-name existed twice across my schema while only one of those had a time-type. It required manually excluding the table-column combination from the condition of my DerivedColumn and now it works well enough.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to find the schema in the projection tab of the source, as shown below:

[image]

If you want to convert an epoch timestamp string column to a Date column, you can use `(toTimestamp(seconds(toInteger(<epochcolumnName>))))` expression in the derived column transformation. You will be able to get the date column as shown below:

[image]

Comment: That doesn't really help. The problem wasn't with the conversion itself, but not being able to tell from merely the column-name, which columns to convert in the first place. Anyway it's done now.